# IMAP search not working with OR and slash / for Microsoft

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, imap

I tried to find e-mail via IMAP with subject "Order XXX/YY/ZZZ"

I do not know if XXX/YY/ZZZ is in subject or body of message so I search with OR

UID SEARCH CHARSET US-ASCII OR BODY XXX/YY/ZZZ SUBJECT XXX/YY/ZZZ - no results

UID SEARCH CHARSET US-ASCII SUBJECT XXX/YY/ZZZ - found

UID SEARCH CHARSET US-ASCII OR BODY XXX SUBJECT XXX - found

I think there is bug in processing OR query with slash or or I am doing something wrong...

The same do not work with GRAPH API with query param
params = {

```
        'search': f'"(participants:{searched_text}) OR (subject:{searched_text}) OR (attachment:{searched_text}) OR (body:{searched_text})"', 

        'select': 'internetMessageId', 

        'top': '1000', 

    }
```

if I remove OR it works
params = {

```
'search': f'"(subject:{searched_text})"', 

'select': 'internetMessageId',

'top': '1000'
```

}

Comment: Are you quoting the string when it contains slashes when using OR?  It’s unclear from your examples if you are.

Comment: I do not quote the string, after run some tests I found out quoting did not help.